# In Inno Setup, how can I get the start type of an existing service. (SERVICE_BOOT_START, SERVICE_SYSTEM_START etc.)

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup, how can I get the start type of an existing service?  (SERVICE_BOOT_START, SERVICE_SYSTEM_START etc.)

I've come across

function QueryServiceStatus(hService :HANDLE;var ServiceStatus :SERVICE_STATUS) : boolean;
external 'QueryServiceStatus@advapi32.dll stdcall';

But SERVICE_STATUS does not include start type.

Comment: It is the `QueryServiceConfig` function that you need to query.

Comment: Thanks TLama.  That did the trick.  I want to mark this as the correct answer but I can't since it's just a comment...

Comment: You're welcome! But, are you sure you can use that function ? How are you going to allocate buffer for that output structure ?

Comment: QueryServiceConfig is returning false but it is still loading up the structure.  I'm confused.  Here is my code:

Comment: I'm confused too. Where is your code :) ? Have you inspected what returns `DLLGetLastError` ? I bet you'll be getting `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`..

Comment: I'm having trouble pasting in my code.  Says it's too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63724/discussion-between-ees-and-tlama).